# query string value not working

Tags: mysql

I have querystring like below

```
var querystring = 'SELECT * from table';  
mySqlNodeConnect.getData2(querystring, ["%" + value + "%"], function (data, error) 
   if (error) {
        reply(error);   
    } else {   
        reply(data);
    }
```

If I run `["%" + value + "%"]` I get the same result as `SELECT * from TABLE`

So the filter is not working

How do I make it work using the variable `value`?

Comment: Please explain what do you have in the `value` variable.

Comment: I'm trying to create search bar. I gave in query string searchtype: Joi.string().required().description('search user by field').valid('Email_ID','Role_Name','Application_CI','all'),
            term: Joi.string().required(),

Comment: Perhaps you meant `var querystring = 'SELECT * from table where some_column like ?';` and/or `value` may be blank.

Comment: @hemanath It would be so much clearer if you could edit your question with those details added!